# Polycom phone not requesting DHCP offer

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, iphone, polycom

My Polycom IP550 phone is not requesting the DHCP address that my windows 2012 server offered it. I have done a wireshark capture on a mirrored port on our switch and you can see that the phone is doing the discover phase of the DHCP cycle and the server sends the offer that shows up on the mirrored port, but the phone doesn't send the request back to the server for the address. In the capture below, the phone eventually sends the request, but sometimes it won't for days. All help with this weird problem will be greatly appreciated! Please note that this is happening to all my phones (about 30).

> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>         1 0.000000000    0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     567    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 1: 567 bytes on wire (4536 bits), 567 bytes captured (4536 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>         2 0.000340000    192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 2: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>         3 6.999589000    0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     567    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 3: 567 bytes on wire (4536 bits), 567 bytes captured (4536 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>         4 7.000159000    192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 4: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>         5 52.998887000   0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     567    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 5: 567 bytes on wire (4536 bits), 567 bytes captured (4536 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>         6 52.999414000   192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 6: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>         7 117.001999000  0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     567    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 7: 567 bytes on wire (4536 bits), 567 bytes captured (4536 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>         8 117.002106000  192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 8: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>         9 180.019910000  0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     590    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 9: 590 bytes on wire (4720 bits), 590 bytes captured (4720 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        10 180.020019000  192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 10: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        11 183.995776000  0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     590    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 11: 590 bytes on wire (4720 bits), 590 bytes captured (4720 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        12 183.996257000  192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 12: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        13 191.995595000  0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     590    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 13: 590 bytes on wire (4720 bits), 590 bytes captured (4720 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        14 191.996147000  192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 14: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        15 206.995303000  0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     590    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 15: 590 bytes on wire (4720 bits), 590 bytes captured (4720 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        16 206.995873000  192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 16: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        17 237.994628000  0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     590    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 17: 590 bytes on wire (4720 bits), 590 bytes captured (4720 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        18 237.995166000  192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 18: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        19 300.993276000  0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     590    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 19: 590 bytes on wire (4720 bits), 590 bytes captured (4720 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Discover)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        20 300.994031000  192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 20: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Offer)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        21 301.995143000  0.0.0.0               255.255.255.255       DHCP     590    DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 21: 590 bytes on wire (4720 bits), 590 bytes captured (4720 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: Polycom_48:ef:3b (00:04:f2:48:ef:3b), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 68 (68), Dst Port: 67 (67)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (Request)
>
> No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
>        22 301.996213000  192.168.10.20         255.255.255.255       DHCP     351    DHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0x1e789653
>
> Frame 22: 351 bytes on wire (2808 bits), 351 bytes captured (2808 bits) on interface 0
>   Ethernet II, Src: SuperMic_47:2e:f5 (00:25:90:47:2e:f5), Dst: Broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff)
>   Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.20 (192.168.10.20), Dst: 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255)
>   User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 67 (67), Dst Port: 68 (68)
>   Bootstrap Protocol (ACK)

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the answer! After a lot of digging into various wireshark captures I noticed that when the problem was happening that there was a lot of IPV6 broadcast and discovery traffic. After additional investigation I found that various computers on our network had Intel nic cards that had a wake on lan function. The computers would sleep and would then "wake" and flood the local switches with IPV6 discovery traffic. I updated the drivers from Intel's site and it solved the problem. While this problem wouldn't have affected our phones if they had been on a separate VLAN, it still would be have been a problem for the PCs in the data VLAN.

I hope this helps someone since it was a hard problem to find!